# Why is request.auth.session undefined?

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, hapi.js

I've created an auth strategy using bell and another using hapi-auth-cookie. However, when I try to set a session `request.auth.session` is undefined. Can someone help me figure out where I am going wrong?

My route:

```
module.exports = [
  {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/create-an-account',
    config: {
      auth: {
        strategy: 'auth0',
        mode: 'try'
      }
    },
    handler: function(request, reply) {
      var credentials = request.auth.credentials;
      request.auth.session.set(credentials);
      return reply.view('create-an-account');
    }
  }
]
```

My auth strategies:

```
exports.register = function (server, options, next) {
  server.register([Bell, Cookie], function (err) {

    server.auth.strategy('auth0', 'bell', {
        provider: 'auth0',
        config: {
          domain: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_DOMAIN,
        },
        password: 'cookie_encryption_password_secure',
        clientId: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
        isSecure: false     // For developing locally
    });

    server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', {
      password: 'cookie_encryption_password_secure',
      cookie: 'sid',
      redirectTo: '/create-an-account',
      redirectOnTry: false,
      isSecure: false
    });
  });
  return next();
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had this issue a little while ago on one of our projects. Hapi-auth-cookie have changed their documentation so they longer use `request.auth.session.set(credentials);`

Here's a [link to the commit](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-cookie/commit/d233b2a3e4d0f03ef53b91b7929b8dbadbff624c)

If you change that line to `request.cookieAuth.set()` instead it should work. A lot of the examples online seem to use the old example which is how we missed it first time.

This was also picked up in another SO answer here > [request.auth.session.set(user_info) not working HapiJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36136528/request-auth-session-setuser-info-not-working-hapijs)